# Copying files with progressbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, copy, progress-bar, shutil

I'm making a simple program that uses tkinter and shutil to copy files, nothing fancy. The problem is that there's no indication of when the process is done, and if I'm copying large folders, the program freezes until it's done copying. I want a progressbar, but don't know how to implement one in tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import shutil


def browseFiles():
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="/", title="Select a directory")
    label_file_explorer.configure(text="Directory Opened: " + filename, bg="grey")
    shutil.copytree(filename, r"J:\PCmover\ziptest\test")


window = Tk()
window.title('Beringia')
window.geometry("700x500")
window.config(background="white")
label_file_explorer = Label(window, width=100, height=4, bg="white", fg="blue")
button_explore = Button(window, text="Choose directory", command=browseFiles)
button_exit = Button(window, text="Quit", command=exit)
softwarename=Label(window, text="Welcome to Beringia!", width=100, height=4, fg="blue")
ver=Label(window, text="Ver 1.0", bg="grey", fg="blue")

label_file_explorer.place(x=0, y=200)
button_explore.place(x=305, y=80)
button_exit.place(x=335, y=120)
softwarename.place(x=0, y=0)
ver.place(x=659, y=479)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Here is an example that uses tkinter's Progressbar widget: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/progressbar-widget-in-tkinter-python/

Comment: Hmmm as far i know, you need to receive the total bytes to be transferred and the amount of bytes transferred per second? and then make a progressbar and go on with the progressbar with the bytes per second like in the example given above, till the _bps_ reaches the total bytes of the folder.